# The MapControl from DevExpress refuses to show the map

Tags: devexpress, bing-maps

I have used the demo project for the MapControl and altered it to my needs.

This works so far. Now I want to repeat this in my actual project and I have copy & pasted all the code and everything is exact the same as in the altered demo project but in the actual project the MapControl shows nothing, only a gray background.

There are no errors.

The only thing I see on the MapControl is the mouse pointer changing when I click on it.

I even copy & pasted the MapControl but still no map is shown.

I can execute code to put items on the map, I get no errors but I can't see anything.

I can execute code to calculate a route and it returns the correct information but I can't see anything.

How is it possible that the MapControl works perfectly in one application and not in another?

Can anybody give me a clue in what direction to search for this?

I posted this problem on DevExpress forum also but unlike usually it stays quiet there...

**EDIT:**
I removed the Copy/Pasted MapControl from the form and started from scratch.
But the result is the same. I get no errors and calculating a route returns correct values, but the map still is too shy and refuses to show itself.

**EDIT 2:**
I created a new Bing Key but the result is the same, no errors but also no maps visible

**EDIT 3:**
I added a MiniMap and after entering the Bing Key the mini maps shows a map on design time
But on runtime its all gone again

**Found the reason finally**

I finally got it working.
In the actual project all forms are derived from a base form
This base form has this overriden method

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        var cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
        return cp;
    }
}
```

When I comment out this code the map finally shows up.
Now I need to figure out why this code is there and if its really needed how I can keep it and still see the map

Comment: Downvoters please feel free to comment, sure you must have a reason for it so share it so I can learn from my mistake

Comment: Basically the whole question was filled with errors. See my edit.

Comment: I assume you are missing a step when just copy & pasting. Perhaps you should go through the [Getting started](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/15051/Controls-and-Libraries/Map-Control/Getting-Started) guide to start from scratch in your actual project.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Yes I already did that and removed the pasted MapControl and started from scratch. But with the same results. No errors but also no map visible.

Comment: I cannot resist `but the map still is too shy and refuses to show itself` is just funny. Did you customize the `ImageProvider` properly as described in step 3? Perhaps you have an invalid API key.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy No I did not custimoze the `ImageProvider` because its not done in their demo project either. I started from one of the demo projects and altered that to my needs. Do you have a link to these steps so I can check if there is anything I missed

Comment: As i already wrote, dig through the [Getting Started](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/15051/Controls-and-Libraries/Map-Control/Getting-Started) guide and start with lesson one. In there you will find step 3 which shows how to setup the `ImageProvider`.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy OK I will do that right now

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I did all these steps before, but did them again just to be sure. Still no map is showing and still also no errors